# Vala TextBuffer backspace() SIGSEG

Tags: text, iterator, gtk, vala, gtk-textbuffer

In order to practice writing on Vala I decided to make a virtual keyboard. Everything works, except Backspace(SIGSEG if press).

https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--end-user-action
I have not found any example of using this function in Vala.
[source](https://gitlab.com/gavr123456789/virtual-keyboard/blob/master/Vala.vala)

Comment: Please add the relevant code directly to the question.

Comment: I tried compiling and running your code, but the signal handlers were not found by Builder, please provide the exact command line you use to compile it as well.

Comment: Also you should try compiling with the `-g` switch on and run your program with a debugger like `gdb yourprogram`.

Comment: to add handlers from xml, you need to add the gmodule-2.0 compilation flag.
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg gmodule-2.0 Vala.vala
Problem solved with help from #Vala chanel on Matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it works if you replace

```
Sas.end.backward_chars (Sas.input.buffer.cursor_position);
```

with

```
Sas.input.buffer.get_iter_at_offset(out Sas.end,Sas.input.buffer.cursor_position);
```

SIGSEG was on line:

```
Sas.input.buffer.backspace(Sas.end,true,true);
```

P.S. input - TextView, end - TextIter.